# /sbin/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -13); systemd is a directory

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-stretch, systemd

My Rpi fails to boot. I get `/sbin/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -13)`.
Following the symlink leads to `/lib/systemd/systemd`. However it seems to be a directory rather than a executable.

Any chance to recover?

Thanks

Comment: *"However it seems to be a directory rather than a executable."* -> I hope not, otherwise things have gone very wrong.  In any case, the first thing you should do is run `e2fsck` on the root filesystem.

Comment: unfortunately it is. How can I run it? it says can't run on mounted FS. Also can't run `shutdown -rF now` - `Failed to talk to init daemon`

Comment: No, don't run it on a mounted filesystem.  The init system [does this automatically at boot](https://www.systutorials.com/241784/how-to-force-a-fsck-during-next-rebooting-of-linux/) if it appears necessary, before the fs is (re-)mounted read-write.  If this system is broken it probably won't happen, so the easiest thing to do is put the card in another computer (where `e2fsck` is available).

Comment: Are you confusing `/lib/systemd/systemd` (a file) with `/lib/systemd/system`, (a directory)? Both exist on a non-broken system.

Comment: I wish I was confusing it, but no, both are a directory. One thing that stands out is that system dir is owned by root, while systemd is owned by `man` (why?!)

Comment: Does your `/lib/systemd/systemd` directory have any content?

Comment: Yes. Can't remember what it was since I gave up and reinstalled. I think it was some services.